# Access multiple GET parameters in PHP without bracket notation

Tags: php, url, query-string

PHP automatically creates arrays in `$_GET`, when the parameter name is followed by `[]` or `[keyname]`.

However for a public API I'd love to have the same behaviour without explicit brackets in the URL. For example, the query

```
?foo=bar&foo=baz
```

should result in a `$_GET` (or similar) like this:

```
$_GET["foo"] == array("bar", "baz");
```

Is there any possibility to get this behaviour in PHP easily? I.e., not parsing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` myself or preg_replacing `=` with `[]=` in the query string before feeding it to `parse_str()`?

Comment: Yes sorry, indeed, parsing it yourself it's gonna be. But it's still just one regex and a loop.

Comment: serialize the array in the url?

Comment: @Dagon I could do that, e.g., allowing `foo=bar,baz` and splitting on `,`. But I'd like to support the basic "multiple identical query keys" method for ease of use of the API. (That's by the way the point: It should be easy to use for others.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to support `?foo=bar&foo=baz`.

[Daniel Morell proposed a solution](https://www.danielmorell.com/blog/parsing-bracketless-multiple-select-inputs-in-php) which manually parses the URL string and iteratively builds up an array when multiple instances of the parameter exist, or returns a string when only one parameter exists (ie; matches the default behaviour).

It supports both types of URLs, with and without a bracket:

```
?foo=bar&foo=baz // works
?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz // works
```

```php
/**
 * Parses GET and POST form input like $_GET and $_POST, but without requiring multiple select inputs to end the name
 * in a pair of brackets.
 * 
 * @param  string $method      The input method to use 'GET' or 'POST'.
 * @param  string $querystring A custom form input in the query string format.
 * @return array  $output      Returns an array containing the input keys and values.
 */
function bracketless_input( $method, $querystring=null ) {
    // Create empty array to 
    $output = array();
    // Get query string from function call
    if( $querystring !== null ) {
        $query = $querystring;
    // Get raw POST data
    } elseif ($method == 'POST') {
        $query = file_get_contents('php://input');
    // Get raw GET data
    } elseif ($method == 'GET') {
        $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    // Separerate each parameter into key value pairs
    foreach( explode( '&', $query ) as $params ) {
        $parts = explode( '=', $params );
        // Remove any existing brackets and clean up key and value
        $parts[0] = trim(preg_replace( '(\%5B|\%5D|[\[\]])', '', $parts[0] ) );
        $parts[0] = preg_replace( '([^0-9a-zA-Z])', '_', urldecode($parts[0]) );
        $parts[1] = urldecode($parts[1]);
        // Create new key in $output array if param does not exist.
        if( !key_exists( $parts[0], $output ) ) {
            $output[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
        // Add param to array if param key already exists in $output
        } elseif( is_array( $output[$parts[0]] ) ) {
            array_push( $output[$parts[0]], $parts[1] );
        // Otherwise turn $output param into array and append current param
        } else {
            $output[$parts[0]] = array( $output[$parts[0]], $parts[1] );
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $slug => $value) {
#whatever you want to do, for example
print $_GET[$slug];
}
```

Comment: This will exactly once print `baz`. `bar` is completely shadowed unfortunately.

Comment: why don't you try ?foo[1]=bar&foo[2]=baz and so on. then $_GET["foo"] will be an array so you can work with it in your code.

Comment: _I_ could do. But the use case is an API, and I want the users of the API to have using it as simply as possible. It's simple cosmetics for the URLs of the API.